# middleware not redirect to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

i have a problem with middleware

my middleware should redirect to a view if the logged in user has the column **'edad' = Null**

User loggin DB:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrk7h.png

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Personales
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        
        if ($request->route()->getName() == "completar" || $request->route()->getName() == "ucompletar") {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->edad != null && Auth::user()->edad != "") {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('/completar');
        }
    }
}
```

i can't find the error because it doesn't work middleware

maybe i'm missing something, just create middleware and view

Comment: are you sure that in your database the value is actually null and not the string 'NULL', because the null in the email_verified_at column looks diffrent ?

Comment: do u register your middleware in `kernal.php` and implement it with routes

Comment: missing log in kernal.php. thanks for help